# Google Cloud Endpoint - Generate PDF

Tags: google-app-engine, itext, google-cloud-endpoints

I am looking to serve a simple throw away PDF using iText from a google cloud endpoint. (It appears that version 5.2+ of iText is supported by GAE)

I have done something similar in JAX-RS where I was able to get the HTTPResponse Object and set the appropriate response header and wrote the contents of the file to the output stream. I have been googling for some time and it appears that I do not have access to the Response object in the endpoint. Could someone confirm this for me?

It appears that my only other option is to create a servlet to do this(found a good example at http://floonit.blogspot.com/2012/07/generate-pdf-using-google-app-engine.html). I am really trying to avoid this because GCE and GAE require you to set up authentication separately which will create a lot more questions and headaches.

Could anyone give me some insight on how to proceed?

Thank you,

-Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) You can store the file in Google Storage. The file could be public or you could use Signed Urls to generate a temporary url to access the file. The API would return either url to the client application and the client application could then invoke it to retrieve the file. The files can be configured to delete themselves after a set period for cleanup purposes.

2.) You can base64 encode the pdf and then return it as an element of the API. If you envision the PDFs to be large this wouldn't be an optimal approach b/c of base64 encoding bloat.